# why the day not equal to 24 hours timezone set to los angeles?

Tags: php, date, timezone, timestamp

*Background: our server PHP set timezone to America/Los_Angeles*

At work, I found this piece of code

```
$a = 1457856000;
$b = $a + 24*3600-1;  

var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a));
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $b));
```

which output:

```
string(19) "2016-03-13 00:00:00" 
string(19) "2016-03-14 00:59:59"
```

quite strange, but when I code as follow:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+8');

    $a = 1457856000;
    $b = $a + 24*3600-1;  

    var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a));
    var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $b));
```

it output:

```
string(19) "2016-03-13 00:00:00"
string(19) "2016-03-13 23:59:59"
```

Could anyone explain why this happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the output of

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set ('America/Los_Angeles');
$a = 1457856000;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a), "\r\n\r\n";

for($i=0; $i<25; $i++) {
    $b = $a + ($i*3600)-1;
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $b), "\r\n";
}
```

and marvel at the weirdness of [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

```
2016-03-13 00:59:59
2016-03-13 01:59:59
2016-03-13 03:59:59 <- and here is why you will be tired all day long next sunday 
2016-03-13 04:59:59
```

edit: "And now i'm wondering if there's any native PHP function or approach to make it convenient to format a date without worrying about the summer time adjustments?"
Yes, there is, see http://docs.php.net/datetime

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$a = new DateTime('2016-03-13 00:00:00');
$b = DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($a)->modify('1 day');
$step = new DateInterval('PT1H');

while( $a <= $b ) {
    echo $a->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\r\n";
    $a->add($step);
}
```

prints

```
2016-03-13 00:00:00
2016-03-13 01:00:00
2016-03-13 03:00:00
2016-03-13 04:00:00
2016-03-13 05:00:00
2016-03-13 06:00:00
2016-03-13 07:00:00
2016-03-13 08:00:00
2016-03-13 09:00:00
2016-03-13 10:00:00
2016-03-13 11:00:00
2016-03-13 12:00:00
2016-03-13 13:00:00
2016-03-13 14:00:00
2016-03-13 15:00:00
2016-03-13 16:00:00
2016-03-13 17:00:00
2016-03-13 18:00:00
2016-03-13 19:00:00
2016-03-13 20:00:00
2016-03-13 21:00:00
2016-03-13 22:00:00
2016-03-13 23:00:00
2016-03-14 00:00:00
```

And

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$a = new DateTime('2016-03-13 00:00:00');
$a->modify('+1 day -1 second');
echo $a->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\r\n";
```

prints `2016-03-13 23:59:59`

Comment: Well that is the reason indeed, thanks a lot... And now i'm wondering if there's any native PHP function or approach to make it convenient to format a date without worrying about the summer time adjustments?